# Game Distribution Website

Tags: wordpress, heroku, unity-game-engine, hosting

So I have this huge game created with Unity, and our installers are about 700mbs in size. We first tried serving the files through a normal wordpress website and hosting services (hostpapa), but found that speeds were being throttled after a while.

I'd like suggestions on how to proceed with the distribution of my game as well as website hosting:
- Should I take the time to make my own server and deploy in Heroku maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Amazon S3 for your file hosting or use a service provider like GoDaddy, HostGator, or BlueHost. Here's a comparison of all hosting services here: http://www.whoishostingthis.com/compare/

Alternatively, depending on the game, you could try getting it on Steam Greenlight if you're trying to distribute the game on a wider scale. Also try asking Green Man Gaming,

Comment: Great idea, will look into those thank you :)!

Comment: Feel free to upvote for future readers =) thanks!

Comment: @PatricioJerí Also remember to accept the answer if it helped.